# How is the GPT's masked-self-attention is utilized on fine-tuning/inference

Tags: nlp, transformer-model, large-language-model

At training time, as far as I understand from the "Attention is all you need" paper, the way that masked-self-attention is used in the decoder is by feeding the output sequence multiple times, each time removing the mask from the next token.

Q1. At inference time, the expected output sequence length is not known. How do you decide on how many masked tokens to add? Do you always fill the max-length of your input with masked tokens and stop when an end of sequence symbol is predicted?

Q2. The GPT inference objective task is a little different. A "query" vector is injected to the model (for example [text1;text2] and [text2;text1] in the similarity task). How is the masking used in this scenario? I would expect that the whole sequence will be injected in only one step with no masking, however this contradicts the masked-self-attention methodology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the standard Transformer, the target sentence is provided to the decoder only once (you might confuse that with the masked language-model objective for BERT).

The purpose of the masking is to make sure that the states do not attend to tokens that are "in the future" but only to those "in the past". The mask looks like this (queries are on the vertical axis; keys and values on the horizontal axis):

```
\ 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 ○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○
2 ● ○ ○ ○ ○ ○
3 ● ● ○ ○ ○ ○
4 ● ● ● ○ ○ ○
5 ● ● ● ● ○ ○
6 ● ● ● ● ● ○
```

This means that for generating the first token, you cannot attend to anything, when generating the second token, you can attend to states of the first token. At the third one, you can attend the first and to the second.

The masking thus emulates the inference time when you can only attend to states corresponding to tokens that have already been generated. It is the same for the standard Transformer for sequence-to-sequence learning and for decoder-only Transformer such as GPT-2.

If you implement the inference efficiently, you do not need the masking. You keep all the previous states in memory, do the attention only with the last query (which corresponds to the newly generated token) and thus get the new states and predict what the next token is. This is done in a loop until you generate the end-of-sentence token.

Comment: Do you have an example of the efficient implementation of inference? It seems to me this would be more similar to seq2seq with attention (vs. the version of attention described in "Attention Is All You Need"?

Comment: Researched further and it is indeed the case that the caching is only needing for autoregressive models. This is done by [hugging face](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/what-is-the-purpose-of-use-cache-in-decoder/958) and also described in [this blog post](https://tunz.kr/post/4)